# Microsoft translator hub- added document doesn't appear in Training Dataset

Tags: training-data, microsoft-translator

I've added a number of documents in various formats (.pdf, .txt) both monolingual and bi-lingual and although they appear in the documents tab they do not appear in the Training, Tuning, Testing or Dictionary windows so I can't select them to perform an initial training.

Answer (score 0):

The document selection is automatically filtered by the language pair for this project. Only documents that match the language pair are listed.
For document files that are not labeled internally, the documents need to include a language ID in the name, the same language you applied to the project you are working on. The naming rule is

<name>_<language>.<filetype>

For example:
*MyFavoriteFile_fr.pdf*
for a French PDF document.

PDF, TXT, DOC and DOCX files are not internally labeled, they need to follow the naming rule. TMX, XLIFF and XLSX are labeled internally. In the XLSX you just have the language ID in the first row.

Tuning, Testing and Dictionary must be available in both languages. For the not internally named files you must have a pair
<samename>_<sourcelanguage>.<filetype>
<samename>_<targetlanguage>.<filetype>

Only for training it is acceptable use monolingual documents. They must be in the target language and labeled accordingly.